# Override Object in S3 Bucket if one with identical key already exists using aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am uploading a file to an s3 bucket using the aws-sdk node module. 
If I attempt to upload an object for which a key already exists in the bucket, I would like it to override the existing object.

Is there a way to achieve that behavior?

here is my code:

````
const uploadedImageData = await s3.upload({
          Bucket: AWS_bucket_name,
          Key: `profile-photo-${username}.jpg`,
          Body: resizedImage,
          ACL:'public-read-write',
        }).promise();```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, uploading file will override by default.

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html

Comment: that is what i would expect.  Im having trouble telling if its a caching issue or if the object is not being over written

Comment: This is correct. The `Key` is the unique identifier for an object. Uploading to the same Key will overwrite the existing object.